# A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, oauth

So i was only able to insatll Oauth bundle with all depencies, i confiquered the files as it was explained in the bundle but i have those 3 errors in my terminal and i can't figure it out.

the first one is :
In FileLoader.php line 174:

The file "C:\Users\EVAN\OneDrive\Desktop\abs_projet\abs_GB\config/packages/security.yaml" does not contain valid YAML: A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping val
ue at line 30 (near "        failure_path: /login") in C:\Users\EVAN\OneDrive\Desktop\abs_projet\abs_GB\config/packages/security.yaml (which is being imported from "C:\
Users\EVAN\OneDrive\Desktop\abs_projet\abs_GB\src\Kernel.php").

the second error is :

In YamlFileLoader.php line 771:

The file "C:\Users\EVAN\OneDrive\Desktop\abs_projet\abs_GB\config/packages/security.yaml" does not contain valid YAML: A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping val
ue at line 30 (near "        failure_path: /login").

and finally the third :

In Parser.php line 811:

A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value at line 30 (near "        failure_path: /login").

Any help?

i tried to qoute  failure_path and login_pah but still got the same errors

Comment: Your security.yaml is not valid, can you edit your question with it